# Spring Boot Server wait for pendig request before accept next

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server, client-server

I have built a web server that provides me with an api to a web page. Because the page can't be scraped easily, I use Selenium to make a few clicks and then read the data. The problem is that selenium takes a relatively long time (~1 second per request) and if a new request comes in during this time, it is accepted before the old one is finished. In this case I have a 50/50 chance that the correct value comes back or that of the other request.

```
[WebPageAPI] received new Restquest for 978383387777
[WebPageAPI] received new Restquest for 978359680709 
[WebPageAPI] returning 0.15 for 978383387777 <--
[WebPageAPI] returning 0.15 for 978359680709 <--
[WebPageAPI] received new Restquest for 978342662424
[WebPageAPI] returning 0.0 for 9783426624241
```

it should be a - b - a - b and it is like a - a - b - b

My Interface looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/WebPage/{isbn}")
public WebPageProduct getPrice(@PathVariable String isbn) {

    System.out.println("[WebPageAPI] received new Restquest for " + isbn);
    WebPageProduct product = WebPageProductPipeline.pipe(productFetcher.fetchProduct(isbn));
    System.out.println("[WebPageAPI] returning " + product.getPrice() + " for " + isbn);

    return product;
}
```

Is it possible to force the server for waiting until the last request is done? Or is there a way to use multithreading and return the right response to the right request?

Comment: 'if a new request comes in during this time' - comes from where? 'it is accepted before the old one is finished' - accepted by whom?

Comment: Web request is async and concurrent, and now you want to criple performance by limiting it to a single request? Also it already returns the correct request, the fact that the logging is mixed doesn't mean the wrong request is returned.